# Booting windows (any version) from an LVM volume

Tags: windows, multi-boot, lvm, lvm2

I'd like to know if any versions of Windows are able to boot from an LVM logical volume, with or without third party extension software.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

Windows has its own version of "LVM" called [Logical Disk Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Disk_Manager).