# Installing Windows on a LVM partition, next to already installed Ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, lvm

I have a SSD driver partitioned with LVM, here is lvm lvs output:

```
LV   VG     Attr     LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Move Log Copy%  Convert
lts  ubuntu -wi-ao-- 103.14g                                           
root ubuntu -wi-ao-- 120.00g
```

`root` partition has Ubuntu for everyday use with Ext4. I'd like to install Windows (8?) on the `lts` partition (no filesystem) - is that possible or will it corrupt my setup (as Windows requires a primary partition)?

Comment: What about going virtual under Ubuntu? With enough RAM and your SSD setup, you'll get good performance and you'll have Windows sand-boxed so nothing bad happens to your host OS. Food for thought.

Comment: Yeah, I'd normally do that but I had problems with my graphics driver under Ubuntu and couldn't get video acceleration under Virtualbox working. And Windows is just installed to play new, video-heavy games. Guess I'll have to get back to this solution and try again.

Comment: From @user459506: Xen might work for this... it's not the easy way, but it might work.  http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=112013

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on this answer:

[LVM on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/235776/booting-windows-any-version-from-an-lvm-volume?rq=1)

I think it's safe to say, no you can't do that. Windows doesn't understand LVM at all. You CAN however implement @KTech's solution. That's the way I'd go.