# LVM dual-boot windows

Tags: windows, lvm

Have the following purposed partion schema ----not worried much about the *nix systems booting - however need to be able to have a native boot Win 7 for some teaching / consulting I'll be doing and not terribly familiar with lvm just yet (much better at VM and MBR using an extended partition)

currently via gdisk

```
Disk /dev/sda: 488397168 sectors, 232.9 GiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): E26BE449-8A6A-4417-AE21-0AFCAA481CAB
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 488397134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 2349 sectors (1.1 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048         1026047   500.0 MiB   8300  
   2         1026048       403458047   191.9 GiB   8E00  
   3       403458048       488396799   40.5 GiB    8E00
```

attempting to go to -> (have only 2Gb on MOBO and NON-UEFI aware Dell D620 BIOS A10

```
/dev/sda
sda1 --200M,-Boot,/EFI,FAT32 (hybrid MBR?)
sda2 --256M,-Boot,/boot,EXT2,Petra
sda3 --256M,-Boot,/boot,EXT2,Heisenberg
sda4 --256M,-Boot,/boot,EXT2,Arch
sda5 --256M,-Boot,/boot,EXT2,Win7
sda6 --191G,LVM,EXT4
    VG-(main system)
LV -10G -Petra VG-main
LV -10G -Heisenberg VG-main
LV -10G -Arch VG-main
LV -40G -Win7 VG-main
LV -30G -usr VG-main
LV -91G -home VG-main
sda7, 40G,LVM,EXT4)
    VG-(Oracle VM
LV -10G -VirtualBox Oracle
LV -30G -Virtual-home Oracle
sda8, 15G,LVM,Swap
LV -15G -n Swap VG-main
```

remarks on any other issues / better schemes I may not see or foresee would be appreciated

Comment: to clarify I'm quite confident the linux systems will see the GPT and fake EFI jsut fine but will this work for allowing windows to coexist and also can win be in the LVM or need to be outside the LVM "box"?

Comment: Hybrid MBR is what I meant by "Fake EFI" didn't remember the termm..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't install Windows on an LVM logical volume. See: [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/634265/installing-windows-on-a-lvm-partition-next-to-already-installed-ubuntu).

I'm also not entirely sure why you're talking about UEFI. Windows 7 doesn't need UEFI to work, it's way simpler to set everything up without it, and furthermore you can't just "fake" a UEFI system.

Also, according to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Windows:_32-bit_versions), you cannot boot 32-bit Windows from a GPT partition at all, and 64-bit Windows requires an actual UEFI system to be able to boot from a GPT partition.

Here's what you should do:

1. Back up any data you care about before messing with your partition table.
2. Switch to a hybrid GPT/MBR parititon table - see the gdisk man page for details on how to do this.
3. Create a normal MBR parition for Windows, install it, and then boot it normally with GRUB.

Comment: tried the hybrid (albeit - may have screwed it up tho), so do i need the additional /boots at the beginning or can I do sda/ sda1 /boot sda2-3 for windows and windows msr and then use lvm for the balance and if so would hybrid just need to on the first partition for using with gpt?

Comment: Basically, Windows just needs to be on an MBR partition. It doesn't matter what else you do with LVM/GPT/etc., as long as that's true. It also doesn't matter if that MBR partition is sda1 or sda5 or etc.

Comment: so the mbr (from the hybrid) just HAS to be whatever Windows is in? teh rest is fine as proposed?

Comment: Yeah - you can have Linux setup however you like; what you've posted in your OP seems to make sense.

Comment: Much thanks to you CmdrMoozy for the quick and easy to understand replies.....hopefully I can return favor soon...

Comment: Wrong! MBR is [severely limited and very easy to corrupt](http://rodsbooks.com/gdisk/whatsgpt.html), for which very reason GPT was created. Hybrid MBR however is a [much more dangerous and ugly hack](http://rodsbooks.com/gdisk/hybrid.html), and is worse than either pure MBR or pure GPT. Further booting an OS via UEFI is MUCH simpler than via PC-AT style ("BIOS-style"). Even further, Windows 7 [CAN be booted from a GPT disk](https://superuser.com/a/791285/203254). And finally, UEFI can [very much be faked with DUET](http://www.rodsbooks.com/bios2uefi/) using Intel's own reference codebase